# Why do division by zero errors get raised for non-zero divisors?

Tags: divide-by-zero, forth, gforth

Consider:

```
9223372034707292159. 1 um/mod
```

For example, it raises a division-by-zero error on my machine.
Why? The divisor is 1 (not 0!) and 9223372034707292159 fits within an unsigned double.

The same goes for *fm/mod* and *sm/rem*.

I'm using Gforth, but these are core Forth words.

Answer (score 4):

See [the specification](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/UMDivMOD) for `UM/MOD ( ud u1 -- u2 u3 )`:

> An ambiguous condition exists if *u1* is zero or if the quotient lies
> outside the range of a single-cell unsigned integer.

If you use a Forth system having a cell size of 32 bits, then in the given case the quotient lies outside the rage of a single-cell unsigned integer, and then it's an ambiguous condition and the behavior of a system is [not specified](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:ambiguous) by the standard.

Certainly, a better error message would be "integer overflow" than "division by zero" in this case.

[update] As it later [appeared](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/issues/32#issuecomment-984195428), in Gforth "the -fast engine does make some compromises speed vs. accuracy of error messages".

Comment: Isn't there more than one Forth standard? Even if there is only one, doesn't it have a name, like ANS Forth?

Comment: If you consider FigForth, Forth-79, Forth-83, Forth-94 (also known as ANS), Forth-2012 — as the different standards, then yes, there are many. But I would consider them as steps (i.e. versions) of evolving the single Forth standard. This question can be also applied  to [ECMAScript standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#History) (as an example) — is it one standard, or many different standards? I would consider them as the different versions.